# when I expose a port in a dockerfile and it build successfully but not responding in a server

Tags: docker

When I run this command **docker build -t my_image .**

I got this as an output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/5 : FROM php:7.2-apache
 ---> f046c4ead123
Step 2/5 : MAINTAINER JLT 7 <j*******t.******@gmail.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2d04942bf1f3
Step 3/5 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8f5c190e13ab
Step 4/5 : CMD ["echo","Hello World!!!...My frst message"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9d67b4f4cf85
Step 5/5 : EXPOSE 8090
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7ad8354944b2
Successfully built 7ad8354944b2
Successfully tagged my_image:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

But when I run this port on the server it is not responding...

Comment: Please add some additional details. Docker file and command you use to verify port would be helpful here

Answer (score 1):

The `EXPOSE` Dockerfile instruction by itself does not publish a container's ports (see the [Dockerfile reference section in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose); the instruction only adds metadata to the image that you built, and allows you to give an indication which ports the service running in your container listens on.

The `EXPOSE` instruction is *optional*, and even without setting that port, you are able to connect to a port that the container is listening on.

In order to make a port accessible;

- first, make sure to have the service in your container listen on a port (your example Dockerfile is based on the official `php:7.2-apache` image, which [listens on port 80 by default](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/a7e2de0e8f2b902bc36be6f5d61c0b4fcd1052ff/7.2/stretch/apache/Dockerfile#L287)
- make sure that the service in your container is listening on any IP-address (`0.0.0.0`), and not on localhost / `127.0.0.1` (because localhost is "localhost" inside the *container*, which means that if your service is listening on localhost, it will only be accessible from inside the container itself)
- when *running* the container, you can map the container's port to the port that your want it accessible on ("port mapping") (also see the [networking section](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) in the documentation.

The `-p` / `--publish` option has a shorthand, and an advanced syntax; I'll use the shorthand syntax in my examples; this notation is using the format: `-p <host-port>:<container-port>`

For example, if your container is listening on port `80`, and you want to publish (or "map") that port to port `8090` on your host;

```
docker run -d -p 8090:80 myimage
```

Your container can now be reached at:

- `http://<ip-address of your host>:8090`
- (depending on your setup): `http://localhost:8090`